# HTML , Display IDs of every Text boxes , when I make focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At my web page, I have several text box controls (eg. Input type="text" ...)
What I would like to do is display every ID for every text box whenever or whatever text box i make focus event.

I already try this.

```
alert($("*:focus").attr("id"));
```

But it return undefined message.

So, Please let me know is there any way to know that which text box, i mean text box ID, is I already focused dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the id of every textbox no matter which textbox you click on. So if you click on textbox1 you want to display the id's of every textbox on that form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a variable on focus, and removing the variable on blur will do the job:

```
var currentFocus = null; //to be defined in the global scope, if you want
                         // to access this property across your whole script

$("input").focus(function(){
    currentFocus = this.id;
}).blur(function(){
    currentFocus = null;
});
```

Comment: While I was checking in jsfiddle you already wrote answer. :) Anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/mYmJ9/

Answer (score 1):

You may need to look if it has an ID or not. I made an example: http://jsbin.com/opocoz/2/edit